# cocos2d custom mask function causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS during draw

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I'm using a Masking function I found somewhere (sorry, I'd like to give credit but can't remember where). It's pretty straightforward, but when I use it, I occasionally (10%) get a crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) somewhere in the application. The location is not consistent, but it appears to always be related to drawing. For example, once it happened on the first "visit" line in this function. More frequently, it happens in the Cocos2d display link.

Here's the function:

```
+ (CCSprite *)maskedSpriteWithSprite:(CCSprite *)textureSprite maskSprite:(CCSprite *)maskSprite {

  CCRenderTexture * rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:maskSprite.contentSize.width height:maskSprite.contentSize.height];
  maskSprite.position = ccp(maskSprite.contentSize.width/2, maskSprite.contentSize.height/2);
  textureSprite.position = ccp(textureSprite.contentSize.width/2, textureSprite.contentSize.height/2);

  [maskSprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE, GL_ZERO}];
  [textureSprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO}];

  [rt begin];
  [maskSprite visit];
  [textureSprite visit];
  [rt end];

  CCSprite *retval = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
  retval.flipY = YES;
  return retval;
}
```

And my implementation:

```
CCSprite* mask = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fp_mask];
CCSprite* fill = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fp_bk];
CCNode* fullBar = [CCSprite maskedSpriteWithSprite:fill maskSprite:mask];
[self addChild:fullBar];
```

Note that if I comment out the invocation of the function and simply add, say, the "fill" object as a child instead, everything works fine.

Also note that this is Mac OSX, FWIW, though my code can also be run on iPhone.

Comment: Is this code running on the same thread as the OpenGL context was created on? Try changing CC_DIRECTOR_MAC_THREAD in ccConfig.h to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize that I shouldn't be doing operations from the main thread onto cocos2d on Mac. I just used the performSelector:onThread: to move over to the [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningThread